# Getting an error message when creating a new project from my template

Tags: visual-studio-2012, project-template

I created a project template from an existing project, in this case it is just a resource DLL.

I replaced some of the data in the projects with the $projectname$ tags so that the contents and the file names take the value that I enter as the project name.  When I create a new project from the template I see 2 dialog boxes, the first one seems to indicate success, i.e.

```
The operation completed successfully.
```

The second one indicate that there was an access violation, i.e.

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I press the OK button, the new project does not show up.  I check the disk and only the project file (vcxproj) has been created, in this case it looks fine, no other files were created.

I checked the vcxproj file and it looks fine.

Other information:

- I am using VS 2012
- VS was started in administrator mode
- The target location is my documents folder

Any idea?

//*eggbox

Answer (score 0):

SolutionName.vcxproj file contains information about additional compiling files. All files which solution must compile must be located under same folder as SolutionName.vcxproj file.

It is very interesting issue which is correlated with next lines of *vcxproj file*

```
<ItemGroup>
<ClCompile Include="Example\AdditionCompiledFile.cpp" />
<ClCompile Include="ConsoleApplication1.cpp" />
<ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
  <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='DebugMD|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
</ClCompile>
```

The issue is reproduced on VS 2013 also.